# Choropleth map not displaying colors

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib, geopandas

I have a dataset
[image]

```
data2 = dict(type = 'choropleth',
           locations = df3['Code'],
           z = df3['Power Consumption KWH'])
layout2 = dict(title = '2014 Global Power Consumption',
             geo = dict(showframe = False, projection = {'type': 'natural earth'}))

choromap2 = go.Figure(data = [data2], layout=layout2)
iplot(choromap2)
```

After that, I created a choropleth, but my problem is the map didn't show any color, it only showed the earth form.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't paste the image of the sample data, paste the text version of it

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and add text.

Comment: Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(20).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your data and found you are missing one important parameter i.e `locationmode = "country names"`. Adding this should work

```
data2 = dict(type = 'choropleth',
           locations = df['Code'],
            locationmode = "country names", # add this 
           z = df['Power Consumption KWH'])
layout2 = dict(title = '2014 Global Power Consumption',
             geo = dict(showframe = False, projection = {'type': 'natural earth'}))

choromap2 = go.Figure(data = [data2], layout=layout2)
iplot(choromap2)
```